# Geospatial segments inclusion

Tags: apache-spark, geometry, geospatial

I have two sets of datas that contains geospatial segments.
In both datasets, a segment data have the following structure :

Segment (ID, startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude)

The problem is that those two datasets come from two different sources, and segments do not match.

I want, for each segments in my Dataset1, the id of a segment from my Dataset2 that 'include the most' the segment. (I am aware that I will never have a perfect result)

Is there a reliable way of doing that ?

(I am using Spark with Scala to compute my datas, but just a theorical solution will be enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into the Magellan library https://github.com/harsha2010/magellan that supports geospatial predicates as contains, within, intersect between points and polygons.

It might be a bit computational heavy to do N*M comparisons, so you could consider converting your segment (or points) into a geohash(es) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) and searching for record with the most overlapping codes for a certain hash length.

Try http://geohash.gofreerange.com/ to explore how each lat/long has this unique box at each zoom level

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
That look good. I have not that much segments and only one zoom level, so I'll try with the Magellan library